# Selecting the account from contact shows error and not able to create any contact

Tags: salesforce

When I select the account from contact when creating it shows the same error and not able to create any contact.
When a new Contact  is inserted  with out Account then throw error message

```
 trigger contacterror on Contact (before insert) {
    for (contact cons : trigger.new){
       if (cons.account==null){
           cons.addError('Account nahi bana hai');
       }
     }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

AccountId is the field on the Contact that stores the related AccountId, so you should be evaluating that instead.  Inside a Trigger, you have access to read all fields on an sObject.  You do not have access to read fields on a related sObject, Account references the entire related Account record.  In order to do that, you will have to do a query.

```
trigger contacterror on Contact (before insert) {
    for (contact cons : trigger.new){
        if (cons.accountId==null){
            cons.addError('Account nahi bana hai');
        }
    }
}
```